# Will I be able to retrieve my checked bags on a 15 hour layover in Narita?

Tags: luggage, airports, layovers, nrt, hidden-city-ticketing

Taking a one-way flight on Singapore Air to Bangkok that has a stopover in Narita and planning to get out during the layover (ultimate destination is Tokyo) since the flight was a lot cheaper. The layover is about 15 hours long, we land in Narita at 7pm and the plane leaves at 11 am the next morning. Will I be able to retrieve my checked baggage in order to prevent my luggage from going to Bangkok?

Comment: Which airline is your original flight on?

Comment: the whole trip is on Singapore Air

Comment: sorry kind of confusing

Comment: So to be clear, you actually only want to fly LAX-Tokyo, and the cheapest option you could find was LAX-Tokyo-Singapore-Bangkok on Singapore Airlines?

Comment: @jpatokal Where did LAX come from?

Comment: Reading it through again, it seems the OP bought a cheap ticket to Bangkok but actually wants to go to Tokyo.  So plans to leave the fight during its layover at Narita. Since it is one way the OP need not worry about cancelled subsequent segments.  And since the layover is overnight the OP likely can short check the bags only to Tokyo.  But that said the OP still needs to deal with entry requirements before the airline will allow boarding the first leg.

Comment: @Berwyn Elementary, my dear Watson: the only two Singapore Airlines destinations at Narita are Singapore (which they have to transit to get to Bangkok) and Los Angeles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narita_International_Airport#Passenger

Comment: @jpatokal Nice sleuthing!

Answer (score 3):

Unless you specially request it, you will not be able to retrieve your bags at Narita, since they will be checked through to Bangkok and transferred directly to the next plane.  You will thus need to bring everything you need with you as carry-on luggage.

However!  There is an option to request at check-in that **they "short-check" your bags to Narita only**.  This is getting harder and harder to do, and is *not* guaranteed, but since you do have a nice long overnight layover of 15 hours, it's possible, and [per anecdotal evidence](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/singapore-airlines-krisflyer/1480243-short-checking-bags-sq.html) Singapore Airlines should allow this.

Also, do you have a ticket out of Thailand? If you're flying one-way, you are likely to be asked for one at check-in, and may be denied boarding without it: [Do I need a bus/train/plane ticket out of Thailand in order to get a Visa-on-Arrival?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24239/do-i-need-a-bus-train-plane-ticket-out-of-thailand-in-order-to-get-a-visa-on-arr)

**Update**: Corrected answer to note that short-checking may actually be a realistic possibility here.

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable to short-check for a 15 hour overnight layover.

Comment: As it is an overnight layover, he should be able to claim his bags and recheck them in the morning.

Comment: I find this answer either incorrect or mis-informed. When checking in luggage at the baggage drop, ground staff usually confirm where your bags are to be sent to. I had a recent PER > SIN > NRT flight with only a 90 min stopover in SIN and they still asked me whether my bags were to be checked through or picked up in Singapore. The problem that the OP will have is a Japanese Transit / Tourist Visa. Unless a long term Visa is obtained, Japan requires proof of exit (ie. a ticket out of the country). If you don't make that flight, you are technically an illegal entrant.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder They do have proof of exit, namely the continuing flight to BKK.  It's not illegal to enter legally and change your plans, as long as they leave by some means before the Japanese entry permit granted at Narita expires, and if the OP is an American citizen, they'll get 90 days, no questions asked.

Comment: @jpatokal I have both an Australian and UK passport, both of which have 90 days (180 in the case of the UK passport), the law is that you still need to show proof of exit if requested and can be denied entry for failing to provide this proof. In practicality however this isn't often checked. Anyway, as OP's exit flight is the next day, overstaying that time after being requested to show the ongoing ticket and being accepted is considered deception, which if caught could face deportation and a permanent ban from the country. Once again, not usually enforced, however this does sometimes happen.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder "Does sometimes happen": got actual cases?  This doesn't sync with my understanding of how Japanese immigration works in practice.  I do agree, however, that the OP would be better off writing their real itinerary on the landing card and having proof of how they're actually going to leave the country.

Comment: @jpatokal Unfortunately I can't dig up too many written accounts in English or Japanese although I have know quite a few people who we not allowed on their inbound flight without a return ticket and at least one person I know was detained for not having a return ticket. Both the Immigration Act and Airport sign say that failure to have a return ticket when not on a Resident Visa may involve fines or deportation. We both know getting checked is rare, but it is in the legal code and there is still a chance of it happening. Apologies if I seemed a bit brash in the first comment.

Comment: @jpatokal A quick check of TIMATIC from the KLM website (https://www.klm.com/travel/ca_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/timatic.htm) says the following; "Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to cover their stay and documents required for their next destination." Also, "Warning: Visitors not holding return/onward ticket could be refused entry ."